# Bettercap/ettercap unable to detect HTTP packets

Tags: kali-linux, arp-spoofing, sniffing, ettercap, bettercap

Basically, I am trying to sniff the network traffic from my other computer. So here's the situation:

I am in a network, where:

```
192.168.1.1 - default gateway
192.168.1.24 - "victim" (my other computer)
192.168.1.20 - "attacker"
```

I am using `bettercap`, but I actually tried `ettercap` before. Steps to reproduce:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
bettercap -i wlan0
> arp.spoof targets 192.168.1.24
> arp.spoof on
```

Then I can check that it works by actually pinging `192.168.1.20`, the attacker IP, and it responds rapidly quick, so I actually ping the default gateway. I guess that's how it works, right?

Then I run some sniffing. Tried multiple tools:

```
urlsnarf - doesn't show anything. It can actually show the localhost traffic (done from the attacker pc)
dsniff - same as above
tshark/wireshark - They are showing some udp/tcp packets, but still no http ones (f.e entering a website, POSTing in a fake user/pass form)
bettercaps net.sniff - actually pretty much the same as tshark/wireshark
```

I uncommented those 2 `iptables` lines from `ettercap.conf`, when I was using `ettercap` (btw, I was doing: `ettercap -Tqi wlan0 -M arp (or arp:remote) // //`

So my question here is: Is there something wrong with my spoofing, or do I need to sniff somehow different?

P.S   I tried those things on both `Kali` and `Blackarch`.
P.S 2 I actually tried bettercaps `dns.spoof` and it also works only on the "attacker" pc, when I ping or go to some website on my "victim" machine, everything works fine - so not fine, cuz it should redirect